# How to show/hide views in superview with autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

There is an different `views` in my custom `UITableViewCell`, I want to show some of them and hide, depends on cell `type`. How to do this?

I added all them in my `xib`, created leading/trailing constraints, but still don't get it. There is no custom width for some of them (if is, i could just change width constraint constant in code), but only based on screen suppositive width. 
[image]

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide a little more detail to get a useful answer here.

Comment: set `view.hidden = YES` not work?

Comment: Sure, view.hidden work, but not fully, it leaves frame, so you need change constraints too